# How do I demonstrate that the given functions solve this system of ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

The system is

$$\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
x'&=&y-x(x^2+y^2-1) \\
y'&=&-x-y(x^2+y^2-1),
\end{array}
\right.$$

and the given solution is

$$x(t)=\sin(t), \quad y(t)=\cos(t) .$$

Since the solution is given, should I just plug them into the system and show that on paper?

Comment: Yes, exactly. $\,$

Comment: this is to do and to show that the left side is equal to the right

Comment: How do you tag a post so that I can find it later?

Comment: @johannesvalks:  you can click on the star under the voting buttons and the post will be added to your favorites list.  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, that's the way it's done.  For instance, since

$x' = y - x(x^2 + y^2 - 1), \tag{1}$

with

$x = \sin t, \tag{2}$

$y = \cos t, \tag{3}$

we obtain

$x' = \cos t$
$ = \cos t - \sin t (\cos^2 t + \sin^2 t + 1)$
$= \cos t -\sin t(1 - 1)= \cos t, \tag{4}$

an identity.  The equation for $y'$ checks out similarly.